# C++ deleting array only deallocates first item

Tags: c++, memory

I want to remove an array from memory, as if it never existed. Here is a simplification of some code I am running. For some reason, deleting the array only deletes the first item.

```
struct PrimeFactor {
    int prime;
    int degree;
};

totalPrimes = 3;

PrimeFactor* primeFactors = new PrimeFactor[totalPrimes];

primeFactors[0].prime = 2;
primeFactors[1].prime = 3;
primeFactors[2].prime = 5;

primeFactors[0].degree = 1;
primeFactors[1].degree = 2;
primeFactors[2].degree = 1;

for (int c = 0;c < totalPrimes; c++)
    cout << c << " , " << primeFactors[c].prime << " , " << primeFactors[c].degree << "\n";

// Prints
// 0 , 2 , 1
// 1 , 3 , 2
// 2 , 5 , 1

delete [] primeFactors;

for (int c = 0;c < totalPrimes; c++)
    cout << c << " , " << primeFactors[c].prime << " , " << primeFactors[c].degree << "\n";

// Prints
// 0 , 0 , 0
// 1 , 3 , 2
// 2 , 5 , 1
```

You see that only the first item of the `primeFactors` array is deleted. What am I doing wrong? How do I completely delete this array?

Comment: attempting to access deleted elements of the array is undefined behavior.  Your effort to prove the 3 deletes happened is thus undefined behavior.  Instead, add a destructor with a cout to your PrimeFactor.

Comment: Once you delete `primeFactors`, any attempt to access its elements is undefined behaviour. And better to use a std::vector.

Comment: `delete` tells whatever allocator you're using that you're done with that memory. The allocator may or may not actually touch the memory you've released, and you shouldn't care because you gave it up.

Comment: @NeilButterworthI have been seeing a bit that std::vector is prefered over arrays in C++. Coming from java and higher level languages, I try to use the simpilist items, like arrays instead of arraylists in java, because they are faster and are less clunky. Why should I use vectors in c++?

Comment: Vectors are  as fast as raw C-style arrays, except for the initial allocation, and are far, far easier to use correctly, as the code you posted illustrates. The same goes for ArrayLists in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **Dangling Pointer**. Dangling pointers arise during object destruction, when an object that has an incoming reference is deleted or deallocated, without modifying the value of the pointer, so that the pointer still points to the memory location of the deallocated memory.

```
delete [] primeFactors;
primeFactors = nullptr; // pointer is no longer dangling
```

Comment: The idea that you should set pointers to null after  deleting them is completely wrong. It simply provides a completely worthless sense of security. What the OP should be using is mart pointers, and not using `new` directly at all..